# Qt: How are arrays or dictionaries passed from qscriptengine?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, moc, qscript

I've created a QScriptEngine and exposed an object's function I can call from js script.

```
engine->globalObject().setProperty("obj", myObj);
```

myObj is a QObject that has a function like...

```
void MyObject::doSomething(int w, int h) {
   ...
}
```

and in my js code, I can call it like...

```
obj.doSomething(5, 9);
```

This works as I expect it would, but I can't find any docs on passing arrays or dictionaries to these functions.  For example, if I wanted to pass an array, how would I define the C++ function so I could do something like this...

```
obj.doSomething([1,2,3], "foo");
```

Would that be something like...

```
void MyObject::doSomething(QVector<QVariant> firstArg, QString secondArg);
```

It's hard to work it out as it when it doesn't work, the call seems to silently fail.

Comment: Have you tried QVariantList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays you have two options

1. Registering the C++ sequence container with the script engine, see `qScriptRegisterSequenceMetaType()`. The function's documentation has an example for an int vector.
2. Use `QScriptValue` as the function's argument. The passed object can then be checked if it is an array (`QScriptValue::isArray()`) and accessed by index using `QScriptValue::property()`

Option (2) also works for dictionaries (objects in JavaScript).

Comment: Option 2 seemed like an easy approach.  I used QScriptValue.property("length") to get the length and QScriptValue("INDEX_HERE") to get a specific index.  Thanks.